# Power Bi - Better solution for multiciple columns

Tags: powerbi

I have created this Power Bi to see stock with summurize Salesorders and Purc orders.
But it's a nightmare how i have made it. How can i do it smarter, so i do now have to create a measure for each period for sale, puch and remaining?

I want a result like this:
[image: Result]

I have tried, but my result is not correct:
[image]

My BI looks like this now:
(Salg Means Sale, Køb means Purchase, Rest means Remaning)
[image: My PBI]

As you can see, I have lot of measures to have this result.

My measures looks like this:

Sale:

```
Sale 121-150 = 

 SUMX(
    FILTER(
        'Sales Line',
        'Sales Line'[Shipment Date] >= TODAY() + 121  && 'Sales Line'[Shipment Date] <= TODAY() + 150
    ),
    'Sales Line'[Outstanding Quantity]
)
```

Purc:

```
Purchase 121-150 = 

SUMX(
    FILTER(
        'Purchase Line',
        'Purchase Line'[Expected Receipt Date] >= TODAY() + 121  && 'Purchase Line'[Expected Receipt Date] <= TODAY() + 150
    ),
    'Purchase Line'[Qty_ to Receive]
)
```

Remain:

```
Remain 121-150 = 
VAR PeriodEnd = 150
VAR Stock1 = SUM(Stock[InStock])
VAR Purc = SUMX(
    FILTER(
        'Purchase Line',
        'Purchase Line'[Expected Receipt Date] <= TODAY() + PeriodEnd
    ),
    'Purchase Line'[Qty_ to Receive]
)
VAR Sale = SUMX(
    FILTER(
        'Sales Line',
         'Sales Line'[Shipment Date] <= TODAY() + PeriodEnd
    ),
    'Sales Line'[Outstanding Quantity]
)

 RETURN (Stock1 + Purc) - Sale
```